# Dynamically add an object property to existing object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

So I have a json object such as:

```
"highChart":{
            "xAxis":{  
               "categories":[  
                  "SYN 13 ",
                  "Settlement",
                  "Service Interaction",
                  "FNOL",
                  "Repair Process",
                  "Rental Experience",
                  "Appraisal",
                  "SYN 14 "
               ],
               "title":{  
                  "text":""
               },
               "labels":{  
                  "enabled":true,
                  "maxStaggerLines":1
               },
               "tickWidth":1
            }}
```

Lets define this as `$scope.chartConfig = highChart`

Now I want to add another property to chartConfig like this:

```
"highChart":{
         "options":{
            "chart":{  
               "height":null,
               "type":"waterfall"
            }},
            "xAxis":{  
               "categories":[  
                  "SYN 13 ",
                  "Settlement",
                  "Service Interaction",
                  "FNOL",
                  "Repair Process",
                  "Rental Experience",
                  "Appraisal",
                  "SYN 14 "
               ],
               "title":{  
                  "text":""
               },
               "labels":{  
                  "enabled":true,
                  "maxStaggerLines":1
               },
               "tickWidth":1
            }}
```

So after initializing `$scope.chartConfig = highChart` I want to add the options property along with the chart property as shown above. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

just like this...

```
$scope.chartConfig.options = {
  "chart":{  
    "height":null,
    "type":"waterfall"
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear what you are asking but you can use `angular.extend()` to merge objects

```
var options = {
    "chart": {
        "height": null,
        "type": "waterfall"
    }
}

angular.extend($scope.chartConfig, options);
```

`$scope.chartConfig` now contains the new properties. If `options` had some properties that were the same as original but different values...the originaal would be updated with those values